# Difference between sharepoint online and sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Kindly elaborate on the  Difference between sharepoint online and sharepoint server?
since we are using sharepoint servers and now going to subscribe for office 365 which will allow us to use sharepoint online service, i would like to know the difference betweeen these two... thank you

Answer (score 5):

First of all SharePoint Server gives you many more possibilities. In SharePoint Online (SPO) environment you are sharing a server with several other tenants (other subscribers) and have limited access to multiple functionalities, e.g.

- Powershell cmdlets:
  [SP on-prem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678226(v=office.15).aspx)  vs [SPO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161364(v=office.15).aspx)
- [View Reports](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/View-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527)
- [Features](http://www.buckleyplanet.com/2014/06/sharepoint-online-vs-onprem-feature-comparison.html)

[Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Websites-in-SharePoint-Online-and-SharePoint-Server-b0b5ea1a-4e99-4f5a-9ef2-ce96c15155e2?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US) you can find Microsoft's comparison of the websites. Bear in mind that SPO public websites will be discontinued and are not available in new tenants already.

On the other hand, with SPO you don't have to worry about the infrastructure, hardware or expansion costs (you just buy another license). 
There's full support and they promise [99,9% uptime](http://blogs.office.com/2013/08/08/cloud-services-you-can-trust-office-365-availability/)

There is a third option: best of both worlds with a SharePoint Hybrid, which sounds like something you are going to make:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj838715(v=office.15).aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn607308(v=office.15).aspx

Have a look also at another Stack Question:
[SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92729/sharepoint-online-or-sharepoint-server-2013)

Answer (score 3):

> When part or all of your data center exists physically on your
>   campus(es), then you have an on-premises solution. Maintaining a
>   SharePoint farm on-premises is startlingly complex and expensive.
>   SharePoint is a Windows Server-based, multi-tier ASP.NET Web
>   application that uses SQL Server for its data tier and relies heavily
>   upon Web standards and the .NET Framework.
>
> When you add in other, related Microsoft servers such as Exchange and
>   Lync, then between physical hardware, electricity, licensing, and
>   support costs, you are facing a huge investment of time, money, and
>   effort.
>
> Imagine if you could outsource some or all of this infrastructure to
>   the proverbial cloud. Cloud providers such as Microsoft operate on a
>   simple premise (pun intended!): you can focus on helping your users
>   and optimizing their experience, and you can leave all the rest
>   (installation, configuration, maintenance, upgrades, troubleshooting,
>   etc.) to your hosting provider.
>
> To that end, Microsoft gives us SharePoint Online and Office 365 as a
>   cloud-based alternative to deploying and maintaining an on-premises
>   farm. Specifically, the Office 365 product is a particular type of
>   cloud computing known as software as a service, or SaaS.
>   Source: https://4sysops.com/archives/sharepoint-2013-on-premises-vs-sharepoint-online/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can point out a major difference between SharePoint Online and SharePoint Server are as follows:-

**SharePoint Online:-**

- Subscription based model
- SharePoint Apps
- Limited PowerShell
- Multi Tennant environment
- Pay for things which your are using
- Service Admin Control

**SharePoint Server**

- Full PowerShell available
- Central Administration
- High cost
- Integration of third party apps

[Top Office 365 consultant](http://ngenioussolutions.com/cloud/office-365-sharepoint-online.html) can help you more about SharePoint Online, SharePoint Server, SharePoint Consulting and much more.